# How to return the value of a "datetime-local" input type from HTML to python flask in strings

Tags: python, html, flask

The purpose of this piece of code is to ask users to input a specific date and time. The input should be sent from the HTML form to app.py, and the python script should check the input and display "available stalls" accordingly.

I tried this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="box box-primary">
          <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Please select a date & time to view available stalls : </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <form method="POST" action="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date and time range:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                      *****<input type="datetime-local" id="reservationtime"
                       name="reservationtime" value="2019-11-15T14:30"
                       min="2019-01-01T00:00" max="2030-12-31T00:00">*****

                    </div>
                    <button type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    <!-- /.input group -->
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the python code is:

```
resultstruct_time = time.strptime(reservationtime,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
reservationDayID = resultstruct_time(6) + 1
reservationHour = resultstruct_time(3)
```

And the error I have been getting is:

> TypeError: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not class 'NoneType'

Could anyone help me solve this problem by telling me how to change the input into str while keeping the input type as "datetime-local?" Thank you!

Edit: It seems that the HTML form is returning nothing to python. But why does that happen? Is there any way to pass back the desired value of "reservationtime?" Here's a repost of all the relevant code down below:

python:

```
@app.route("/FilterStallsPage",methods = ["GET","POST"])
def DisplayFilterStallsPage():
    stallsInfoDict, availableStallsCount = filterAvailableStalls()
    return render_template('FilterStallsPage.html',stallsInfoDict =   stallsInfoDict, \
    totalStalls = len(stallsInfoDict), availableStalls = availableStallsCount)


def getReservationTime():
    if request.method == "POST": 
        reservationtime = request.form["reservationtime"]
        return reservationtime

def filterAvailableStalls():
    reservationtime = getReservationTime()
    resultstruct_time = time.strptime(str(reservationtime),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

    reservationDayID = resultstruct_time(6) + 1
    reservationHour = resultstruct_time(3)
    (the rest block of irrelevant code not included)
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="box box-primary">
              <div class="box-header">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Please select a date & time to view available stalls : </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body">
                  <form method="POST" action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Date and time range:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                          *****<input type="datetime-local" id="reservationtime"
                           name="reservationtime" value="2019-11-15T14:30"
                           min="2019-01-01T00:00" max="2030-12-31T00:00">*****

                        </div>
                        <button type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                        <!-- /.input group -->
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing nothing is being returned. You could try adding print at the place where the python receives the response. Print type of the response received then start debugging from there. Try type casting to string. Try checking if nothing is returned. Sometimes nothing is returned and its a noneType object.

```
print(type(reservationtime) ) #debugging
print(reservationtime)        #debugging
resultstruct_time = time.strptime(str(reservationtime),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

edit-helping-debug

```
def getReservationTime():
    if request.method == "POST": 
        print('made to POST')
        return "test-string"
        #reservationtime = request.form["reservationtime"]
        #return reservationtime
```

okay if you get the print and it doesn't return a noneType it means you only have to fix the commented lines.
If it doesn't make it there you have to fix the get reservation code that handles generating the post. I haven't worked with flask enough to give you the exact answer just keep fiddling with it and see wether a post request is even occurring.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your method and it seems that nothing is returned. Could you help me look at the edited part in the question and see what can be done?

Comment: Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks! I managed to figure it out. The error occurred because 'POST' was never reached, something went wrong in the 'GET' process.